# Cannot call modal popup of master page in child page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, master-pages, modalpopupextender

I am using a modal popup for to display login box. The modal popup is in the master page and associated with a LogIn link therein. Now I want to call the same modal popup in a child page using a different link button. The modal popup can be called by the LogIn link of master page but I want to add this second control (linkButton) in child page, which can call the modalpop of master page.

I tried this in child page:

```
function LogIn2()
{
$find("programmaticModalPopupBehavior").show();
} 

<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClientClick="LogIn2">Log in</asp:LinkButton>
```

Reference: [multiple TargetControls for the ModalPopup](http://forums.asp.net/t/1422287.aspx#faq_v3_6_3)

How to call the functional modal popup of master page from a control in child page??

**Update:**

This is in masterpage:

```
<ajax:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="linkLog" CancelControlID="linkClose" BackgroundCssClass="cssModal"                       PopupControlID="panelPopUp" BehaviorID="programmaticModalPopupBehavior" PopupDragHandleControlID="panelDrag"></ajax:ModalPopupExtender>
```

Comment: Is ModalPopupBehaviorID the actual ID of the modal popup, as in the UniqueID?

Comment: @James its the behaviorID of the modal popup, not the modal popup's ID. Using the latter also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I m not sure about this but let me confirm are you using the control of ajax like given below

```
 <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ImageUploaderEx" runat="server"  BehaviorID="ImageUploaderBID" TargetControlID="Link Name" CancelControlID="Cancel"  PopupControlID="Panel to be open" OnCancelScript="hideUploader()"></asp:ModalPopupExtender>
```

If Yes then you can use this same modal with a different name, If this doesnt work let me know I will try my best

try this if it works

```
((ModalPopupExtender)Page.Master.FindControl("ModalPopupExtender1")).Show();
```

and add this as well

```
using AjaxControlToolkit;
```

Comment: Please check the question update for the modal popup control usage.

Comment: The page refreshes on clicking the link

Comment: Yes it will you will have to repoen these popup on pageload complete

Answer (score 0):

Add an OnClientClick for the LinkButton, like this:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text="Login 2" OnClientClick="return LogIn2()" ...>
```

Put the JavaScript function in your master page, and after showing the popup, have the method return false to prevent the LinkButton from doing a postback:

```
function LogIn2()
{
    $find("<%=ModalPopupExtender1.UniqueID%>").show();
    return false;
}
```

As an alternative, you may also add return false to the OnClientClick of the LinkButton, after the LogIn2 function has executed, like this:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text="Login 2" OnClientClick="LogIn2();return false;" ...>
```

Comment: Gives error: The name 'ModalPopupExtender1' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Replace ModalPopupExtender1 with the ID of your modal popup extender.

Comment: The link refreshes the page when i use this: $find("ModalPopupExtender1").show();

Comment: The ID of my modal popup is same, check updated question.
And yes the modal popup is in master page

Comment: Put the JavaScript function in your master page, and just call it from the child page. It will work better that way anyways, because then you won't need to add a JS function to every page that opens the popup.

Comment: Doesn't work then also.
And I already have a LogIn link in the master page. I have to provide an alternative LogIn link in a single child page only, so loading the javascript for all the other pages is not required.

Comment: Yes, but the login link in the master page is the target control of the dialog. What happens when you put the LogIn2 function in the master page per my example?

Comment: The page refreshes on clicking the LogIn link button.

Comment: Well then how will the javascript function be called if i keep onClient to return false??

Comment: Using the 1st method: The page refreshes again
Using the 2nd method: I get a null object error in the javascript function

Comment: I keep messing it up. See edited answer. I added "return LogIn2();" to the OnClientClick event of the LinkButton.

Comment: You're still getting the null object error? That probably means that it's not finding the modal popup. Can you try using document.getElementById("<%=ModalPopupExtender1.UniqueID%>") to see if that makes any difference? We can change it back afterwards, but I want to rule out the obvious first.

Comment: did you add the return false at the bottom of the JS function, and return LogIn2() in the OnClientClick of the LinkButton. It definitely shouldn't be posting back if you're returning false in OnClientClick.

Comment: I had not added return false while using document.getElement; now when i have added it, nothing happens on clicking the login button. All still. If i use $find method instead of document.getElement then i get null object error.